# Cannot update plesk panel

Tags: ubuntu, plesk-onyx

I'm using Plesk panel to host my websites. Recently, it stops getting updates. I can see error stating I should run "dpkg --configure -a", but when I do, server stoprs responding and I have to reboot it.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.

Where should I look further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable reason for such behavior is the Ubuntu kernel bug - [#1579135: AppArmor profile reloading causes an intermittent kernel BUG](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1579135). Newer AppArmor packages are not compatible with the old kernel.

Here are the steps to resolve it:

1.   Temporarily remove AppArmor post-install scripts in order to prevent AppArmor from reloading:

```
# mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/apparmor.postinst ~/
# mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/apparmor-profiles.postinst ~/
```

2. Disable AppArmor:

```
# service apparmor stop
# service apparmor teardown
# update-rc.d -f apparmor remove
```

3. Run dpkg --configure -a to fix the initial error:

```
# dpkg --configure -a
```

4. Upgrade Ubuntu kernel to version 4.4.0-38.57 or newer and reboot the server. For example, for version 4.4.0-72:

```
# apt update
# apt install linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic
# sudo reboot
```

5. Move back AppArmor post-install scripts and reconfigure apparmor-profiles package:

```
# mv ~/apparmor.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/
# mv ~/apparmor-profiles.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/
# dpkg-reconfigure apparmor
# dpkg-reconfigure apparmor-profiles
```

6. Start AppArmor:

```
# service apparmor start
```